# Linq Any - Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am getting the following error:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Datos.Especialidad'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

When trying to correct the following code:

```
IQueryable<Medico> listaMedicos = 
    from unMedico in context.Medico
    select unMedico;

if (medico.Especialidad.Count > 0)
{
    listaMedicos = FiltrarPor(listaMedicos, 
        x => x.Especialidad.Any(e => e.ID == (medico.Especialidad.FirstOrDefault().ID)));
}

return listaMedicos.ToList();
```

The relationship between "Medico" and "Especialidad" is a many to many as follow

[image]

Comment: What exactly is `FiltrarPor` doing?  You probably just need to capture `medico.Especialidad.FirstOrDefault().ID` in a variable and use that in your lambda instead.

Comment: this is "FiltrarPor" signature  IQueryable<TEntity> query,Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null)

and executes: 

query = query.Where(filter);

Comment: You should add that code to the question.

Comment: @RufusL That's being used in a `Where` so they do want a `Any`.

Comment: Try doing `var id = medico.Especialidad.FirstOrDefault().ID;` and then `listaMedicos = FiltrarPor(listaMedicos, x => x.Especialidad.Any(e => e.ID == id));`

Comment: What if `medico.Especialidad` contains more than one item? Do you really only want the medics that have the first item as a specialty? Wouldn't you want to get all medics that have one or more of the specialties? (sorry if my Spanish to English translation is wrong, hope you know what I mean)

Comment: And if you do really want the first, you don't need `FirstOrDefault()` since you've already checked for `.Count > 0`. You can just use `First()`.

Comment: @RufusL I know what you mean, but in this particular case, that medico.Especialidad always contain one member, as It is being filled from a combo in the view as design

Comment: Please don't `.FirstOrDefault().ID`. Maybe `.FirstOrDefault()?.ID` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
if (medico.Especialidad.Count > 0)
{
    var medicoId = medico.Especialidad.FirstOrDefault().ID
    listaMedicos = FiltrarPor(listaMedicos, 
        x => x.Especialidad.Any(e => e.ID == medicoId));
}
```

actually, better, would be:

```
var medicoEspecialidad = medico.Especialidad.FirstOrDefault();
if (medicoEspecialidad != null)
{
    var medicoId = medicoEspecialidad.ID
    listaMedicos = FiltrarPor(listaMedicos, x => x.Especialidad.Any(e => e.ID == medicoId));
}
```

Comment: This is what juharr suggested in the comment, and after trying it it works. So  I am accepting It as the correct answer. Thanks